# How to use grep to find files identical to suffix?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have this files: a.h, b.h, count.sh. And I use this operation

```
find . | grep ".h$"
```

And as result I have all 3 files but want only a.h, b.h? Where is my error?

Comment: This might help: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: the `.` refers to "any single char". to make ita  literal `.`, you need to escape it, ie `grep '\.h$' files`. This is a duplicate Q, would you mind just deleting it? Thanks and good luck.

Comment: Use `find . -name '*.h'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the `.` since this way it match anything since that is its meaning in regex. So try `"\.h$"`.